# How to guarantee order of primary key and timestamp in oracle database

Tags: oracle

I am creating some record which have id, ts ... So firstly I call select to get ts and id:

```
  select SEQ_table.nextval, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP from dual
```

and then I call insert

```
insert into table  ...id, ts ...
```

this works good in 99 % but sometimes when there is a big load the order of record is bad because I need record.id < (record+1).id and record.ts < (record+1).ts but this conditional is met. How I can solve this problem ? I am using oracle database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use the result of a sequence for ordering. This might look strange but think about how sequences are cached and think about RAC. Every instance has it's own sequence cache .... For performance you need big caches. sequences had better be called random unique key generators that happen to work sequenctially most of the time.

The timestamp format has a time resolution upto microsecond level. When hardware becomes quicker and load increases it could be that you get multiple rows at the same time. There is not much you can do about that, until oracle takes the resolution a step farther again.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `INSERT` trigger to populate the `id` and `ts` columns.

```
create table sotest
(
id number,
ts timestamp
);

create sequence soseq;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SOTEST_BI_TRIG BEFORE
  INSERT ON SOTEST REFERENCING NEW AS NEW FOR EACH ROW   
  BEGIN
    :new.id := soseq.nextval;
    :new.ts := CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
  END;
/

PHIL@PHILL11G2 > insert into sotest values (NULL,NULL);

1 row created.

PHIL@PHILL11G2 > select * from sotest;

    ID TS
---------- ----------------------------------
     1 11-MAY-12 13.29.33.771515

PHIL@PHILL11G2 >
```

You should also pay attention to the other answer provided. Is `id` meant to be a meaningless primary key (it usually is in apps - it's just a key to join on)?